# How to divide two complex numbers in C#

Tags: c#, division, complex-numbers

I am trying to divide two complex numbers in C# but can't get it to work! I'm pretty sure it is my formula that is wrong, but I do not understand what the problem is with it.

I have tried to modify the formula a few times but with no success. This is because I have never studied Complex numbers (or any math similar to it) and am therefore pretty lost.
I tried this formula: http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/complex/dividing/dividing_complex.html but had trouble converting it into code.

I am grateful for any responses! Thank you

```
        public Komplex div(Komplex a, Komplex b)
    {
        Komplex resDiv = new Komplex();

        resDiv.re = a.re / b.re - a.im / a.im;
        resDiv.im = a.re / b.im + a.im / b.re;

        return resDiv;
    }
```

EDIT: The program is supposed to take inputs like this (example): (3+2i) / (1-4i)

Comment: what exactly is the result you are getting from this?

Comment: What are your expected inputs and what is the expected output?

Comment: [This is how .NET's `Complex` does it](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs,205)

Comment: Input example:(3-1i) / (5-3i)

Comment: What's the definition of `Komplex`?

Comment: How does that 'example' map onto an instance of this `Komplex` class?

Comment: @canton7 Yes I have seen it but I do not understand which method to use and how to properly implement it.

Comment: Why not use the C# [Complex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex?view=netframework-4.8) type, or are you purposefully reinventing the wheel to practice?

Comment: @Amy The complex number will be split into two parts, real part and the imaginary part (re and im) and each object holds one complex number. That is why there is Komplex a and Komplex b (two numbers)

Comment: Your math is wrong. Must first work on math, and only when math works you can go on to code. Read this: http://www.mesacc.edu/~scotz47781/mat120/notes/complex/dividing/dividing_complex.html

Comment: @TheSmile then how's it different from .NET's Complex? Which complex type doesn't have real and imaginary parts?

Comment: To everyone asking why I'm not using .NET's complex type it is because I'm trying to learn and understand programming as well as possible and therefore try to solve issues from scratch. Thank you for your time and quick answers! I really appreciate all of your inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is how `.NET's Complex` class does it](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/Complex.cs,205) (adjusted for your variable and type names):

```
public static Komplex div(Komplex a, Komplex b)
{
    // Division : Smith's formula.
    double a = a.re;
    double b = a.im;
    double c = b.re;
    double d = b.im;

    Komplex resDiv = new Komplex();

    // Computing c * c + d * d will overflow even in cases where the actual result of the division does not overflow.
    if (Math.Abs(d) < Math.Abs(c))
    {
        double doc = d / c;
        resDiv.re = (a + b * doc) / (c + d * doc);
        resDiv.im = (b - a * doc) / (c + d * doc);
    }
    else
    {
        double cod = c / d;
        resDiv.re = (b + a * cod) / (d + c * cod);
        resDiv.im = (-a + b * cod) / (d + c * cod);
    }

    return resDiv;
}
```

---

Why aren't you using .NET's [`Complex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.complex?view=netframework-4.8) type though?

```
var a = new Complex(3, -1);
var b = new Complex(5, -3);
Console.WriteLine(a / b);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I am not using .NET's type since I am learning programming and want to do as little "behind the scene" work as possible. With this code snippet I can examine it and understand what is going on!